# mocha + jsdom + React TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, jsdom

I'm just getting started unit testing a React 0.10.0 component with mocha 2.3.3, jsdom 6.5.1, and Node.js 4.1.1. I have this for my unit test:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var sinon = require('sinon');
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var view = require('../student-name-view.js');

describe('The student name view', function() {

    var renderedComponent = null;
    var nameChangedStub = sinon.stub();
    var nameSubmittedStub = sinon.stub();

    before(function() {
        global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
        global.window = document.parentWindow;
        this.renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            view({
                nameChanged:   nameChangedStub,
                nameSubmitted: nameSubmittedStub
            })
        );
        this.nameInput = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(renderedComponent, 'input').getDOMNode();
    });

    describe('should notify the controller', function() {

        it('when the name field changes', function() {
            TestUtils.Simulate.change(this.nameInput);
            expect(nameChangedStub.called).to.be.true;
        });

    });

});
```

And this is my simple React view:

```
var React = require('react');

var StudentNameView = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return React.DOM.div({
            id: 'name-container',
            children: [
                React.DOM.p({
                    children: 'Enter your name'
                }),
                React.DOM.input({
                    id: 'nameInput',
                    onChange: this.props.nameChanged
                }),
                React.DOM.button({
                    id: 'doneButton'
                })
            ]
        })
    }

});

module.exports = StudentNameView;
```

When I run the test, I get this stack trace:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
  at Object.EventListener.listen (node_modules/react/lib/EventListener.js:21:15)
  at Object.merge.ensureScrollValueMonitoring (node_modules/react/lib/ReactEventEmitter.js:315:21)
  at Object.ReactMount._registerComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:282:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:305:36)
  at Object._renderNewRootComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:57:21)
  at Object.ReactMount.renderComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:359:32)
  at Object.renderComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactPerf.js:57:21)
  at Object.ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument (node_modules/react/lib/ReactTestUtils.js:57:18)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/student-name-view-test.js:19:44)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of jsdom are you using?

Comment: I updated the question to have all the version numbers.

Comment: What happens if you change from `jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow` to `jsdom.jsdom().defaultView`?

Comment: @AlienBishop: using `defaultView` instead of `parentWindow` as mentioned by @limelights worked for me.

Comment: Changing to `defaultView` only results in a new error for me, and I have [reported a bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5046). I think the problem is my old version of React—the problem goes away if I upgrade to the latest version of React.

Comment: defaultView / parentWindow:
This is same as document.defaultView and document.parentWindow. parentWindow is IE specific implementation where as defaultView is for all other browsers. https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1381#issuecomment-182972032

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm posting the solution in case it helps anyone else. It's explained in detail [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5046), but in a nutshell: You must ensure that the DOM is ready before React is loaded by Node's module loader. You can force this by using mocha's `--require` option and specifying a file that contains the jsdom setup.

In my case, I created a file named `setup.js` in my `test` directory with the following contents:

```js
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.navigator = {userAgent: 'node.js'};
```

And now my test runs successfully with this command:

`mocha --require ./test/setup.js`

Comment: For people using es2015, don't import jsdom. I spent a couple hours trying to get this to work, and using require instead of import made it work. I don't know why, I'm just happy it finally works...

Comment: I'm using jsdom with `import` syntax just fine. It depends on your Babel configuration.

Comment: Why not `global.navigator = global.window.navigator`?