# mocha TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, jsdom

I have an app using react_on_rails gem. Everything renders well. When I came to use Mocha + TestUtils + jsdom to write tests, I've got error message

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined`

I found an answer with the similar setting and same error message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920213/mocha-jsdom-react-typeerror-cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-unde). Followed the instruction suggested. And now I bumped into an error message coming from react-on-rails:

```
client/node_modules/react-on-rails/node_package/lib/ReactOnRails.js:238
ReactOnRails.resetOptions();
^

ReferenceError: ReactOnRails is not defined
```

Since my app is a complicated one, in order to reproduce the same error message, I wrote a barebone react app and use the same testing tools.

**hello.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Hello extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }    
}
```

**test.js**

```
import Hello from '../hello.jsx';
import addons from 'react/addons';
const TestUtils = addons.addons.TestUtils;
import React from 'react';
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
import assert from 'assert';
import ror from 'react-on-rails';

describe('render correctly', function() {

  it('should render', function() {
    let comp = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Hello/>);
    let h1 = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(comp, 'h1');
    assert.equal(h1.getDOMNode().textContent, 'Hello world');
  });

});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test/tests.js --require test/setup.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1",
    "react-on-rails": "^5.2.0",
    "react-tools": "^0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "glob": "^4.3.5",
    "jsdom": "^3.1.1",
    "mocha": "2.3.3",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^0.2.1",
    "mocha-lcov-reporter": "0.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
}
```

I didn't have to include the npm package `react-on-rails` for this simple app. But the point is to reproduce the error message I had with react on rails so I had it in the app.

When I ran `npm test`, I got the exact same error message:

```
node_modules/react-on-rails/node_package/lib/ReactOnRails.js:238
ReactOnRails.resetOptions();
^

ReferenceError: ReactOnRails is not defined
```

Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's appropriate to include the ReactOnRails npm library for Mocha tests. If you want to do true integration testing with ReactOnRails, use capybara tests. See /spec/dummy of https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/tree/master/spec/dummy for examples.

I'm the principal author of React on Rails.

Comment: In my rails app, I didn't explicitly include ReactOnRails npm library. I was trying to simulate the issue via a much simpler setting by including the npm library. The reason that I didn't choose to use capybara is because of testing running time. It's not ideal for unit testing. So I thought by using TestUtils.Similate function, I should be able to get it running fast. Isn't that a right way to go?

Comment: @swingfuture If you can get this figured out, please share as this will help the community at both https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/ and https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial.